# How can I configure JBoss AS 7 to support PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, jboss

I have a web application developed mostly in PHP and MySql, but need to deploy it on a JBoss AS 7 server.  I have installed and configured JBoss 7.1 and integrated it with Eclipse, and imported the PHP app into a Dynamic Web Project.  The webpage works, as far as HTML, but when I try to access any PHP page, It just shows the PHP code.  How can I deploy PHP5 so as to interpret PHP, and integrate a MySQL data source?

Answer (score 0):

since JBoss using java as server side programming you cannot run php code in jboss. 
you can integrated jboss AJP with apache using module mod_jk and connect jboss to mysql using mysql-connector for JDBC.